# Particle system hair lines are facing downwards. How to make them facing upwards?

Tags: particles

I was creating a doughnut following a famous Blender tutorial on YouTube. I duplicated the upper part of a Torus and made them into a separate object. At this point, when I added a particle system (hair), the hair lines were facing up.

Then, I deformed the object using the sculpting mode. At this point, if I add a particle system, the hair lines look like below; they are facing downwards. I have searched Google and found answers and posts about moving the origin, but it did not work. Is moving the origin the answer? I am using Blender 2.81.

[image]

The project file can be downloaded from this URL: https://filebin.net/pyj0vqo1787i4y1r/test.blend?t=uco3o5we

Comment: Are your normals flipped?

Comment: @Moog Yes, but I wonder why this happened; I don't remember changing the normal manually.

Comment: No idea, I haven't tracked down the reason why it sometimes happens, I think it might be a bug as I have sometimes seen this on loading a blender file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a Normal problem. Particles have a reference direction based on the poly surface. Try to flip your normals as you rather a hairy doughnut than a bearded one. This is a good article: https://www.katsbits.com/codex/flip-normals/

Comment: Flipping the normal solved the problem, but I wonder why this happened in the first place. I had not change the normal. Does using some of the buttons in the Sculpting mode flips the normal?

Comment: Something might have happened during the creation process. Usually toruses are initially outward facing normals. Maybe you have negatively set the local Z force for the particle system. You might try to reproduce the error starting all over.

Comment: @Flávio it's helpful to explain how to fix the problem e.g. screenshot of the menu and/or hotkey, external links are generally used for reference and should not substitute for a full answer here.  Please read [answer] for more information.

Comment: Yes. I am fairly new to 2.8 and I know a lot of hotkeys have changed. Is it still simple 'n'?

Answer (score 0):

Solve it by changing the parameter at Solidify Modifier:

**Rim: checking both 'Fill' & 'Only Rim'**

Still don't know why it works.